# List.contains for long values doesn't return expected value (groovy)

Tags: groovy

I've been playing around with Groovy and ran into this interesting thing.
Checking whether a list of longs contains a particular number works when checking integer values, but not when checking long values.

```java
​List<Long> list = [5, 7, 3]

println (5 in list) // true
println (5L in list) // false

int i = 5
long l = 5
println (i in list) // true
println (l in list) // false

Integer i2 = 5
Long l2 = 5
println (i2 in list) // true
println (l2 in list) // false
```

I ran this code on https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/. This seems broken to me (or at least highly counter-intuitive). I'd expect there to be some issues within the implementation of List.contains and what comparison operator it is using?
I can work around that, but I'm wondering if there is something that I'm missing or if that is actually intended behavior?

Comment: The elements in the list are integers, as you can confirm by executing `println (list[0].getClass())`.  I'm not sure how Groovy deals with type annotations, but I get the exact same results if I change the list to `List<String>`, which seems odd to me.

Comment: Solution can be seen here: http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_multi_methods

Comment: funny thing. the behaviour is different with java. for ex. next code in java `List<Long> list = new ArrayList(); list.add(5);` put `long` into `list` while in `groovy` `integer`.  Suppose it's related to no type check in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), i.e., no type information at runtime. Since groovy is a [*dynamic language*](https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-typing-vs-dynamic-lang) (*dynamic dispatch* for methods calls with Meta-Object Protocol, etc.), there is no type checking/static compilation by default.

So your groovy code is roughly equivalent to this groovy code:

```
def list = [5, 7, 3]
// no type checking by default, so generics types does not matter due to type erasure
[...]
```

or this *pre-generics* java code:

```
   List list = new ArrayList();
   list.add(5);
   list.add(7);
   list.add(3);

   System.out.println(list.contains(5)); // true
   System.out.println(list.contains(5L)); // false
   [...]
```

If you compile that in java (better with -Xlint) you get the classic [***Unchecked Error Messages***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

From groovy 2.0, you can turn on type checking/static compilation with `@groovy.transform.TypeChecked` / `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` (static compilation triggers also type checking):

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class Test {
    static main(args) {
        List<Long> list = [5, 7, 3]

        println (5 in list) // true
        println (5L in list) // false

        int i = 5
        long l = 5
        println (i in list) // true
        println (l in list) // false

        Integer i2 = 5
        Long l2 = new Long(5)
        println (i2 in list) // true
        println (l2 in list) // false        
    }
}
```

So that you get a compilation error:

```
[Static type checking] - Incompatible generic argument types. Cannot assign java.util.List <java.lang.Integer> to: java.util.List <Long>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize the list with integers. Simply initialize your list with long values:

```
List<Long> list = [5L, 7L, 3L]
```

Now you will get what you expect.